# Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такие рамки в таблице

Tags: html, css

Через разные способы пыталась уже сделать эти рамки, но постоянно получается, что каждая ячейка живет своей жизнью и закругляются только рамки каждой ячейки по отдельности. Вот нужно сделать так. [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Answer (score 3):

Вот так?

```css
.aaa {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px 5px;
  background: #8b4cff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.bbb {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #1b1824;
}

.bbb:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">
  <div class="bbb"></div>
  <div class="bbb"></div>
  <div class="bbb"></div>
  <div class="bbb"></div>
  <div class="bbb"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    td {
      width: 400px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 20px;
      color: white;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .ph {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      background-color: grey;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .star {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: yellow;
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="black">
  <center>
    <h1 style="color: white;">Электронная библиотека</h1>
    <div style="background-color: navy; width: 420px; border-radius: 20px; padding: 20px;">
      <center>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="ph"></div>
              <div class="star"></div>Content</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="ph"></div>
              <div class="star"></div>Content</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="ph"></div>
              <div class="star"></div>Content</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="ph"></div>
              <div class="star"></div>Content</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: а свой html css проверяли на валидность ?

Comment: Тег `center`, серьезно? `<body bgcolor="black">` -- Что за эхо 20го века?

Comment: Напишите лучше, я думаю человеку это будет полезнее чем просто комментарий с насмешкой)